# Check username availability using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to check if a username is available or not.

I'm following this: http://phppot.com/demo/live-username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery-ajax/

I keep getting the error alert, whats wrong?

**The Ajax call**:

```
function checkAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "check_availability.php",
        data:'username='+$("#username").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
        },
        error:function (){alert("error");}
    });
}
```

**Server side:**

```
<?php
/* this is check_availability.php  file */
  $con=  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','user') or die(mysqli_error());
  if($con)  { echo 'connected';}
  $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
  $query="SELECT * FROM username_list WHERE     username='$username' ";
  $result=  mysqli_query($con,$query);
  $rowCount=  mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($rowCount>0) {
      echo "<span class='status-not-available'> Not Available.</span>";
  } else {
      echo "<span class='status-available'> Username Available.</span>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: See theres a line in my code which tells to alert("error") . I see only this alert. Not any other error message

Comment: What is the status of ajax request in network tab? is it 200 or 500?

Comment: Ymartin, where I can find that network tab? I am not expert. May tell more simply?

Comment: Please see in my code.  Do u see some thing missing?

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well.

Comment: put alert message inside success message like alert(data) let me know what it will give

Comment: Do this: 1) on your html page, right click on the page and click on "inspect element" 2) Then click on the "network" tab 3) Then in network, click on "XHR" tab". 4) Now do the action that will trigger your ajax call.You will see the call in the "XHR" log. Click on the log.That will show you the response status

Comment: <html>
<head>
<style>
body{width:50%;}
#frmCheckUsername {border-top:#F0F0F0 2px solid;background:#FAF8F8;padding:10px;}
.demoInputBox{padding:7px; border:#F0F0F0 1px solid; border-radius:4px;}
.status-available{color:#2FC332;}
.status-not-available{color:#D60202;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
/*      codes of body is given above     */
</body>
</html>

Comment: @ Sel Vaa --  it gives nothing. because function inside success isn't executing.

Comment: network>logging   showing this-----                              The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. index.php
no element found check_availability.php:15:3
no element found index.php:15:3

Comment: put direct url in ajax post url like url:http:localhost/foldername/check_availability.php

Comment: @Sel Vaa----i inserted alert(data) as u suggested. and now i get these as alert:   http://dealintech.com/sendEmail/a.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very hard to determine whats going on without some more information as mentioned and a test case.

Here is what is probably happening in your case: The ajax call fails, I can say that for sure since the error functions executes

> **error** - Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
>   A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an

The problem is probably that the target is not reachable - change your code and then open your console to see whats really going on. I also changed your ajax call to a better format:

```
function checkAvailability() {
   var username_tocheck = $("#username").val(); //Probably you want to validate it before you send
   $.ajax({
           url: "check_availability.php", // Try full url too
           data: { username :  username_tocheck },
           method: "POST",  //  POST | GET
           dataType: "html", // xml,json,script,html
           beforeSend: function() {
                 $("#loaderIcon").show();
           },
           success:function(data){
                 $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
                 $("#loaderIcon").hide();
           },
           error:function ( jqXHR, textStatus ){
                alert("error: " + textStatus);
                console.log("error: " + textStatus);
           }
   });
}
```

As you can see I made allot of changes:

1. Changed the data to an object.
2. Changed `type` to `method`.
3. Added `dataType` - set to whatever you need.
4. Moved the loader icon to the `beforeSend` handler - you probably prefer to hide it in a `always` handler.
5. Exposed the actual error.

Have fun exploring.

Comment: Recently I have had a little  idea of json. Then how can I fetch data using json?

Comment: very simple - on the server side echo the json `echo json_encode($arr)` and parse the string on the client side - [demo on github](https://gist.github.com/jonsuh/3739844)